# rowCount() returns incorrect number of rows

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to create a online/offline bar for on my user profile. It seems to not work 100% because it is always showing online. I'm using the following script for it :

```
<?php 
    $user = $req_user_info['username'];
    $sql = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM blog_active_users
                                       WHERE `username` = {$user}");
    $num_rows = $sql->rowCount();
    if (!$sql || ($num_rows < 0)) {
        echo '<div class="span2 alert alert-error"><h4>offline</h4></div>';
    } else if ($num_rows > 0) {
        echo '<div class="span2 alert alert-success"><h4>online </h4></div>';
    }
?>
```

I already tried the script with `num_rows > 0` and `== 0` but nothing seems to work.
I also tried to do it on the other way first `num_row > 0` and then `num_row < 0` but that didn't work.

Also for the answer for the following people. This is my the script for the answers:

```
    <?php 
$user = $req_user_info['username'];
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM blog_active_users WHERE `username` = '".$req_user_info['username']."'");
$num_rows = $sql->rowCount();
if(!$sql || ($num_rows == 0)){
echo '<div class="span2 alert alert-error"><h4>offline</h4></div>';
}else{
echo '<div class="span2 alert alert-success"><h4>online </h4></div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Try to think *what* you are selecting.

Comment: Using `COUNT(*)` and the doing `rowCount()` doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting `COUNT(*)`, therefore you're request will always result in 1 answer : the row count itself.

You can either set an alias on COUNT and use it...

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS my_count FROM blog_active_users WHERE `username` = {$user}");
$num_rows = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->my_count;
```

... or select everything :

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM blog_active_users WHERE `username` = {$user}");
$num_rows = $sql->rowCount();
```